# OnItemClickListener not working in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi I am making a simple recyclerview.And I also want to add OnItemClickListener.
So I did it implementing Adapter.Onitemclicklistener in ViewHolderClass.But it is not working.

I think I add OnItemClicklistener in wrong way but can someone gave me the solution.

Here is my adapter

```
package com.example.niyamat.golfscoreboard;

 import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Adapter;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Niyamat on 12/3/2015.
*/
 public class ScoreBoardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoreBoardAdapter.ScoreBoardViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private Hole[] mHoles;

public ScoreBoardAdapter(Context context, Hole[] holes) {
    mContext = context;
    mHoles = holes;
}

@Override
public ScoreBoardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.scoreboard_layout, parent, false);
    return new ScoreBoardViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ScoreBoardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mHoleName.setText(mHoles[position].getHoleName());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mHoles.length;
}

 public class ScoreBoardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    public TextView mHoleName;
    public TextView mResultLabel;
    public ScoreBoardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mHoleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.holeName);
        mResultLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Yey we got it",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myViewHolder.viewID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("NIC", "Clicked on View::");
        }
    });
```

Eaziest way to do it

Comment: It is good code. set listener to viewholder. Super easy and work

Comment: To use this solution with Android Data Binding, it was with a reference to `ViewDataBinding binding` in this method from the adapter class `protected void updateBinding(..)` .  So in my code where I had a layout and views for a news feed it was `newsItemBinding.layoutNewsItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {..});`  Nice light-weight solution  .. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

2-step solution:

1) Use a custom listener `RecyclerItemClickListener` to get the click:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // TODO Handle item click
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
        );
```

2) Full code listing for `RecyclerItemClickListener` .. add this class to your code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using an `OnItemClickListener` in your `ViewHolder`. You also never set which `View` should use the listener. Instead you should be using a `View.OnClickListener`, which will set the `OnClickListener` for each view in your `Adapter`:

```
public final class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView mHoleName;
    public TextView mResultLabel;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mHoleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.holeName);
        mResultLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultNumber);

        // Set the view to use the OnClickListener you have implemented
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Yay we got it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

---

Also, if you want to have a callback to your `Activity` or `Fragment` this is by far the easiest way that I have found to do it:

```
public class ScoreBoardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoreBoardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemSelected(Hole hole);
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    private Hole[] mHoles;

    public final class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView mHoleName;
        public TextView mResultLabel;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mHoleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.holeName);
            mResultLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultNumber);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemSelected(mHoles[getAdapterPosition()]);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    // The rest of your ScoreBoardAdapter code
    ...

}
```

This will give your `OnItemClickListener` back a `Hole` object, but you can set your `OnItemClickListener.onItemSelected` method to accept any object(s) your adapter can provide.

Answer (score -2):

There is an Implementation of a working Listener in this tutorial:http://www.chatapp.info/en/projects/populating-listview-from-mysql-database.html

Comment: Broken link. Also, seems to be for ListView not RecyclerView